# Run Ruby on Rails migrations on specific Google App Engine service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've been working on a Ruby on Rails API and I'm using Google Cloud Platform, specifically Google App Engine, to deploy my app. I followed the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/rails/using-cloudsql-postgres). So far so good. My app was successfully deployed and I could successfully run the migrations. Let's call this environment **production**.

The thing is I need to deploy a sort of **staging** environment. For the moment I had to create another project to solve my problem and consider that as my staging environment. Now, I don't think this is necessary, actually seems to be redundant.

I've prepared another database `my_app_db_staging`. And I created a `staging.yaml` file stating to run as another instance with the service name **staging**. The service was successfully deployed. Where is the problem? Well, running the migration. I'm using the `appengine` gem. So, to run the migrations you're supposed to run:

```
bundle exec rake appengine:exec -- bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

But as the documentation states:

> The `appengine` gem provides the Rake task `appengine:exec` to run a command against the most recent deployed version of your app ***in the production App Engine environment***.

So, no clue on how to run the migrations against my recently created **staging** service.

Comment: Have you tried something like `bundle exec rake appengine:exec -- bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=staging` ?

Comment: Indeed. I've tried all the combinations of that rake task pointing to my new env. But nothing happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked deeper into the `appengine` gem, and it has an option. It lacks more documentation so you don't have to waste time looking for an answer:

```
rake appengine:exec GAE_CONFIG=staging.yaml -- bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

The options can work together with `GAE_SERVICE`, but the yaml file has to have the same name, otherwise you'll get an error.